# Using a list in pytholog

Tags: python, prolog, logic-programming

I'm trying to define a knowledge base where a disease has a list of symptoms. Here's a snippet:

```
import pytholog as pl
diseases_kb = pl.KnowledgeBase()
diseases_kb([
     "disease(diabetes, [frequent_urination, extreme_thirst])",
     "disease(pneumonia, [cough, fever, shortness_of_breath])",
])
```

However, when I query this:

```
print(diseases_kb.query(pl.Expr("disease(diabetes, Symptoms)")))
```

it just returns `['No']`.

It looks like, lists are not being recognized by pytholog. I tried using (), list(), whatever syntax that I hope would work but nothing works. The library removes '(' and ')', and splits the queries by ',' which I think is the reason why it's not recognizing lists. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `disease(diabetes, [frequent_urination, extreme_thirst])` I assume it's because the kb  doesn't know by default that a list of things following a disease are called _symptoms_.  So when you ask for Symptoms, the kb has never seen that word before and doesn't know what it is.  Anyway, I'm no expert, and this is just a guess.

Comment: Rules such as `disease_symptom(pneumonia, cough)` etc. would be easier to understand and work with. No need to create lists yourself.

Comment: @brebs you're right that it is easier to understand but given a long list of diseases and symptoms, I think it might be more optimal to use a list. As a workaround though, I will be defining them individually. 

I also need to create a function to see if the set of symptoms a patient has is a subset of a disease's list of symptoms which I think is also easier to do if I can make the symptoms list work. Functions like ```setof```, ```findall```, etc. don't seem to work on pytholog either. (I'm new to logic programming so maybe there's a much easier way?)

Comment: Why use pytholog, rather than a full-featured Prolog such as https://www.swi-prolog.org/ ?

Comment: @brebs Have to deploy it on streamlit since I need to create a shareable user interface for it. Sadly, libraries like pyswip don't correctly work on streamlit, I'm assuming it's because of issues in dependencies. Pytholog is the only one that works but it doesn't have all features.